# How can I establish a connection with an IPv4 peer when my node has only IPv6?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, connection, port

I have a channel with someone who only has IPv4. I only have IPv6. How can I redirect the port in my LND to accept IPv4?

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41133/how-does-computer-in-ipv4-network-communicate-with-computer-in-ipv6-network

Comment: Hi user209474, I edited your question to try and better summarize the topic in the title. Please feel free to roll-back or further edit your question if you feel that I didn't get it exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

#c-lightning has an automatic system for assigning ports for connections to the LND. Configuration needs to be set appropriately at ur routing modem.